# Selectbox on change to effect within the same table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 select boxes with class starttime and endtime and if startime is chosen then values in end time will be disabled which are prior to the starttime. At the moment as all classnames are same if I change one starttime its effecting all end times, is there anyway I can prevent changing the end time of other tables row?

**JavaScript**

```
$("select[class='starttime']").on("change", function(){
    $("select[class='endtime']").empty();
    var startix = $("select[class='starttime'] option:selected").index();
    $("select[class='starttime'] option").each(function(ix, el){
        if (ix >= startix) {
            $(this).clone().appendTo("select[class='endtime']");
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rt194bxd/

**UPDATE 1**

If that's not possible because of no proper identifier then will setting up id to TR (table row) does help in anyway?

I did setup id for each TR in this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rt194bxd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing `.appendTo("select[class='endtime']");`, appendTo the specific select element; i.e. the select element coming after the one that's clicked.

We have to traverse the DOM and find it.

```
 $("select[class='starttime']").on("change", function () {
     var $this = $(this);     
     var nextSelect = $this.parent().next().children().first();         
     nextSelect.empty();
     var startix = $("select[class='starttime'] option:selected").index();
     $("select[class='starttime'] option").each(function (ix, el) {
         if (ix >= startix) {
             $(this).clone().appendTo(nextSelect);
         }
     });
 });
```

**Update:**

Above code is a bit buggy. The correct way is shown below:

```
 $("select[class='starttime']").on("change", function () {
     var $this = $(this);     
     var nextSelect = $this.parent().next().children().first();
     console.log(nextSelect[0].tagName);
     //$("select[class='endtime']").empty();
     nextSelect.empty();
     var startix = $("option:selected", $this).index();
     $("option", $this).each(function (ix, el) {
         if (ix >= startix) {
             $(this).clone().appendTo(nextSelect);
         }
     });
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rt194bxd/4/

Comment: Just a minor issue, the endtime is working as per the first starttime not the table row starttime

Comment: Yeah I realized. Updated post.

Comment: How can I change `parent().next().children().first();` if the endtime selectbox is in next tr > second td ??

Comment: `parent().parent().next()` gives a reference to the next tr element. From there work your magic. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select.starttime").on("change", function(){
    // Access "<tr />" elem.
    // This can be resolved better (this assumes there will be exactly 
    // one select.starttime per row. I'd recommend giving [unique] ID to
    // each row (or select.endtime) and passing it to select.starttime
    // (in extra attribute perhaps).
    var parent = $('tr')[$("select.starttime").index(this)];
    var $this = $(this);
    // Clear select.endtime of same table row
    $("select.endtime", parent).empty();
    // Get selected option index of this <select />
    var startix = $("option:selected", $this).index();

    // Run through this <select /> options
    $("option", $this).each(function(ix, el){
        if (ix >= startix) {
            $("select.endtime", parent).append($(this).clone());
        }
    });
});
```